# Syntaxerror: Unexpected Token , in Hawk (fresh npn install)

Tags: javascript, node.js, plivo

I am in the process of learning Nodejs and WebRPC. I am for all intents and purposes, a novice.

I installed the Plivo (http://plivo.com) API for nodejs and when attempting to run it I had an issue with Const which I resolved by running my test file with --harmony appended to the start of the command, after this I have gained the error

Syntaxerror: Unexpected token ,

This error falls on line 506 of 
\hawk\lib\server.js

The relevant section of code is;

```
const artifacts = {
        ts: authorization.ts,
        nonce: authorization.nonce,
        host,
        port,
        hash: authorization.hash
    };
```

line 506 is host,

I do not see the problem.

At this point, all I am trying to do is initialise the plivo API. I have no other calls to it.

I have deleted the hawk folder and done a fresh npm install hawk, can anyone else suggest anything?

edit:
As of writing the post, I attempted to load hawk directly in a script rather than as a dependency through plivo. It still brings up the same error so it won't be a problem with plivo.

Edit 2. 
Seems it was a versioning issue. My system had v0.12 installed. I attempted to update it twice, both times the install went back to v0.12 despite uninstalling it first.

Cleared appdata\roaming\npm and appdata\roaming\npm-cache as well as deleting any remaining node files in "c:\program files" before reinstalling. I now have 8.x installed and the syntax error is no longer showing.

Thanks

Ken

Comment: Sounds like you need to update your Node installation. Node correctly supports `const` and shorthand properties like what you see there.

Comment: I figured that, ran a version check (0.12.2) I then uninstalled Node, downloaded the latest, installed it and the version check returned the same version number. When looking up the const error, some one on Stack Overflow mentioned a version 4. Not sure how I would get that when the latest download I could get was 0.12

Comment: Are you running on some kind of alternative hardware? Are your sources out of sync? Node v0.12 was released a long time ago. Try visiting [the Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/) to install the latest version.

Comment: I have just finished manually deleting anything and everything involving node from my computer and did a fresh install. I am now running off node 8.x and the syntax error is no longer showing up. Will update my post. How do you close a question?